# Creating a dup function inside a module - clashes with dup property of array

Tags: d

If I create a `dup` function inside my D program, I can no longer use the `dup` property of an array. This code works

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  double[] v = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
  writeln(v.dup);
}
```

But this code returns "clash.d(9): Error: function clash.dup (double x) is not callable using argument types (double[])"

```
import std.stdio;

double dup(double x) {
  return x;
}

void main() {
  double[] v = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
  writeln(v.dup);
}
```

How can I define a `dup` function in my program and not lose the `dup` property of arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alias` it into the local overload set:

```
alias dup = object.dup;
```

right below your own `dup` function definition.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can you tell me where the "object" comes from or provide a reference?

Comment: It is the implicitly imported module in druntime: http://dlang.org/phobos/object.html the dup function is one from there (as is class Object, Exception, alias string, and other basic global names.). Aside from being automatically imported, there's nothing special about it, so it follows all the normal name lookup and hijacking rules <http://dlang.org/hijack.html> which is why the alias line works.